# The entropical way to count the number of cases?

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello I want to count the number of cases like this.

$A_1 + A_2 + ... + A_p = T$

When $A_1 = 0$, the number of cases can be computed by combination of repetition and the value is

$\binom{(T-0)+(p-1)-1}{(p-1)-1}$

When $A_1 = t$, that is

$\binom{(T-t)+(p-1)-1}{(p-1)-1}$

But my idea is entropy maximizing.

Now, there are p of independent variables. And let $n_i$ be the number of independent variables that have  the value of $i$.

So the total number T can be rewritten as

$A_1 + ... + A_p = \sum^{T}_{i=0} i*n_i = T$

And the number of cases of occupation number set ${n_i}$ is

$S\{n_i\} = \frac{p!}{n_0!...n_\infty!}$

Then, I applied the Lagrange multiplier method to S

$\tilde{S} = \frac{p!}{n_0!...n_\infty!} - \beta (\sum^{T}_{i=0} i*n_i - T)$

If $n_i$ and $p$ is large and $\tilde{S}$ is maximum, then

$n_i \approx e^{-\beta i} $

But the entropy maximizing seems like unnecessary condition.

And I can't check the result is correct.

I need your help, please..

Comment: I checked and approximately the result of entropy maxmization and that of first method. How can it be possible?

Comment: What is the question?  Number of cases of what?

Comment: Is entropy maximization method is identical to first method? If yes, Why are they identical?